# Adding a web link to alert view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Hi, I want to implement an alert view with a web link attached.

Is it possible?
It should not show like a button in an alert view.

Comment: Please make WrightsCS the correct answer.

Comment: It isn't the correct answer. The question clearly states that "it should not show like a button in an alert view".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UIAlertView

```
UIAlertView *_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Search Google?" 
                                                 message:@"Launch Google and search for something?" 
                                                delegate:self 
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Nah" 
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Google It!",nil];
[_alert show];
```

### UIAlertView Delegate

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if( buttonIndex == 1 ) /* NO = 0, YES = 1 */
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. Specifically the point "it should not show like a button in an alert view".

Comment: @Travo LOL ... UIAlertView is deprecated anyway, find another solution!!

Answer (score 2):

Add text view to the UIAlertView and enable the property with this

```
textview.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

it will work!!

Answer (score -1):

plz employ `initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:`. You can add the link title as an `otherButtonTitles` and the employ

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{}
```

to fire some action, such as go to the web page, when the link button is clicked.